# Youtube/vimeo iframe won't play in firefox

Tags: javascript, events, iframe, youtube

I am embedding a youtube/vimeo video onto my site with an iframe.

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/{$entity->getYoutubeVideoID()}" ...></iframe>
```

The `{$entity->getYouTubeVideoID()}` bit is smarty template code syntax. I don't think that is the problem because the video uploads and plays fine in Chrome and IE9 and up. The video also uploads to firefox and safari fine, meaning I can see the video and it's the right one. But when I click the video it does not play in either firefox or safari.

What is interesting is that the other events are triggered. That is, on mouseover the play buttons on the videos change. On the youtube videos, the button in the middle with the play icon starts out as grey and on mouseover turns to red. So the iframe is registering events. But, it won't play on click. I have no idea where to go from here.

The only other event handlers I have on the iframe is this one but I doubt that is messing it up:

```
$(window).blur(function(){
    if($('iframe').is(':focus')){
        mySwipe.slide(mySwipe.getPos(), 1000);
    }
});
```

(mySwipe refers to the swipe.js slideshow library)

Comment: What happens when you press the big play button?

Comment: @AhmedNuaman The play button changes from red to grey but the video does not play. This behavior is erratic as well.

Comment: Are you doing any CSS transforms on the iframe?

Comment: @AhmedNuaman the only styling on the iframe are the `width:100%` and `height:100%` I set in the html.

Comment: Ok so if you were to specify the height and width according to whatever the embed code YouTube provide you with (you can find this on the watch page), does that work? There is still a bug with FireFox regarding Flash and the sizing of the player where controls get skewed: http://dropshado.ws/post/4085720152/css-transforms-breaking-flash

Comment: @AhmedNuaman Thank you for showing me the bug. No, unfortunately putting the width and height to 560 and 315 did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply could not get embedded videos to play inside the swipe.js library (or any other touch enabled jquery library). My solution was to extract thumbnail images from vimeo/youtube APIs and use them as placeholders in the slideshow. Then register a click event on the thumbnail that opened the video in a lightbox.

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue with playback buttons in firefox also.  I was using a html5 Doctype, so I added the following after the youtube url

&html5=1

maybe this might help you.

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is six years old, but I recently had this problem and all of the solutions on the internet did not work.  But I figured it out for my site:

If you have a secure site (HTTPS) and you embed a youtube video with the code posted here,

`iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/{$entity->getYoutubeVideoID()}"` ...

... Firefox will block it, because that is "Mixed content."   HTTP is unsecure, so it is not allowed to show.

**Youtube is an HTTPS site**, so including that "s" in your URL will allow it to play in Firefox and IE without having to disable security.

Answer (score 0):

Flexslider 2 basically solved it. Swipe.js is wonderful, but with playing youtube/vimeo in a slider Flexslider works better.